# How to run a single test in Azure DevOps build

Tags: azure-devops

I've tried the following to run a single test in Azure DevOps build script. I have only 2 tests and I'd like to only run one of them.

**Azure DevOps build script for testing**

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Smoke test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Test*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --filter Name~TestMethod2'
```

**Results of test**

```
Starting test execution, please wait...

A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
No test matches the given testcase filter `TestMethod2` in C:\agent-orsa-ssp\_work\2\s\RsSolution7\UnitTestProject1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\UnitTestProject1.dll
```

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> How to run a single test in Azure DevOps build

According to the error message:

> No test matches the given testcase filter `TestMethod2` in
> `UnitTestProject1.dll`

It seems we do not have the test whose name contains `TestMethod2` in the `UnitTestProject1` project, like:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {

    }
```

To resolve this issue, please make sure you have the test whose name contains `TestMethod2` .

For example on official document [Unit testing C# with MSTest and .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/core/getting-started/unit-testing-using-mstest/)：

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Prime.Services;

namespace Prime.UnitTests.Services
{
    [TestClass]
    public class PrimeService_IsPrimeShould
    {
        private readonly PrimeService _primeService;

        public PrimeService_IsPrimeShould()
        {
            _primeService = new PrimeService();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void IsPrime_InputIs1_ReturnFalse()
        {
            var result = _primeService.IsPrime(1);

            Assert.IsFalse(result, $"1 should not be prime");
        }

        #region Sample_TestCode
        [DataTestMethod]
        [DataRow(-1)]
        [DataRow(0)]
        [DataRow(1)]
        public void IsPrime_ValuesLessThan2_ReturnFalse(int value)
        {
            var result = _primeService.IsPrime(value);

            Assert.IsFalse(result, $"{value} should not be prime");
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Then I use the `--filter Name~IsPrime_InputIs1_ReturnFalse` to run a single test `IsPrime_InputIs1_ReturnFalse`, it works fine:

[image]